# Creating a Flow in Salesforce to Send an Email Alert to the Lead Owner if an MQL is not Touched Within 12 Hours

Tags: workflow, email-alert

I am trying to create a flow in Salesforce that sends and email to the "lead owner" but also to individual marketing users if a lead is not followed up on within 12 hours.

I built a flow that looks at:

- A lead is marked as status = Marketing Qualified
- If the status does not change after 12 hours, trigger an alert.

I have watched video after video on how to set this up and am running into errors.

Not sure what I have done wrong. See below.

[image]
[image]

Edited:
[image]

Comment: I would look into the definition of `{!EmailBody}` and `{!SubjectLine}` and make sure they validate successfully

Comment: What do you mean by looking into the definition? I created these exactly like what someone in a Youtube video showed. How can I check that it is validated?

Comment: other possibility is lead is owned by a queue in which case the Recipient Email Address expression is invalid as it assumes Lead is owned by a User

Comment: I tested it specifically with a lead that is indeed owned by a User. What would you suggest I check?

Comment: please use [edit] and show how the variables `EmailBody` and `SubjectLine` are defined

Comment: I switched it so that it just pulls from an email template I created in the "Email Alerts" Setup section, so now the only variable is "record Id" and it is still giving me issues. I added another image.

Comment: switching to an email alert was a good idea - but the recordId for the email alert has to be an Id and you are passing it as a string (i.e. the User.Email). Each email alert has a target object when you created the alert. you need to pass the Id of that object

Comment: Thanks for your help! How do I know what my target object should be? I'm creating alerts based on a lead being updated, so is that my target object? Lead.Id?

Comment: if the email alert was defined on Lead, then you pass Lead.Id

Comment: Thank you! I just updated it to pass the Lead.Id and I am still having validation errors. "The "SLA_Alert_Email" element in your flow has validation errors." Any idea of what I should check now?

Comment: this is perplexing and I'd suggest starting with a new flow - with just an email alert that you can make work; then modifying step-by-step adding in more bits until you reproduce the error